# How to read sqllite file from jdbc

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I am trying to store my mozilla firefox history into a text file and save it.

Here is my program

```
Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        // create new file
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");       
          stmt = c.createStatement();
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( "SELECT * FROM COMPANY;" );
```

As per my understanding it will get the data from company table in test database.

but i want to get the data from the file **places.sqllite** and store it contents into a normal text file.

any suggestions for a better approach will be appreciated.

Comment: _"it will the data from company table in test database"_ -- sorry, can you clarify what this means?

Comment: please have a look at edited content.......

Answer (score 1):

first of all use this classes

```
 org.sqlite.SQLiteDataSource
 org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader
```

from `JDBC` driver to work with `sqlite` (*wth JDBC*) like this

```
 BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filePath))
 SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
 dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlite:/path/to/places.sqllite");

 ResultSet executeQuery = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("select * from table;");
 while (executeQuery.next()) {
      writer.write(executeQuery.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i));
   }
```

Comment: newBufferedWriter method is expecting 3 arguments.....and what is filepath?whether it is the path of the file we want to write to or any other?

Comment: `newBufferedWriter` method is actually expecting `2` arguments but don't worry about it, `filepath` is path to `txt` file you want to `store` your content in it from `Sqlite` table, before that please `create `the file `txtfile.txt` and use it like this `Paths.get("path/to/txtfile.txt")` .

Answer (score 0):

You create a test.db and the name of your table is company. Try to change of the db